# How To Make Make Auto Sum Calculation Input Field

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/F2wEK/4/:

**HTML**

```
cost 1 :<input type="text" class="cost" name="cost1" /><br />
cost 2 :<input type="text" class="cost" name="cost2" /><br />
cost 3 :<input type="text" class="cost" name="cost3" /><br />
cost 4 :<input type="text" class="cost" name="cost4" /><br /><br />
sum : <input type="text" id="sum" readonly />
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".cost").each(
        function(){
        $(this).keyup(
            function(){
            calculateSum()
                });
            });
        });

        function calculateSum(){
            var sum=0;
            $(".cost").each(
            function(){
                var vl = this.value.replace(',','');
                if(!isNaN(vl) && vl.length!=0){
                    sum+=parseFloat(vl);
                    }
                }); 

            $("#sum").val(sum.toFixed(2));
            }

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input.cost').keyup(function(event){
      // skip for arrow keys
      if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40){
          event.preventDefault();
      }
      var $this = $(this);
      var num = $this.val().replace(/,/gi, "").split("").reverse().join("");

      var num2 = RemoveRougeChar(num.replace(/(.{3})/g,"$1,").split("").reverse().join(""));

      console.log(num2);


      // the following line has been simplified. Revision history contains original.
      $this.val(num2);
  });
});

function RemoveRougeChar(convertString){


    if(convertString.substring(0,1) == ","){

        return convertString.substring(1, convertString.length)            

    }
    return convertString;

}
```

Why it can not be auto sum if i enter 100000, 1000000, 10000000, more bigger...? How to make it work with thousand, million or billion number? Please help me guys..

Comment: It looks like it is working to me...

Comment: it is not working if i'm enter for each input field (for example) 100000 or 1000000 or 10000000 or bigger than that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem is your replace function, it only replaces the first `','` not all. In your `calculateSum()` function you do this:

```
var vl = this.value.replace(',', '');
```

I would propose to

```
var vl = this.value.split(',').join('');
```

instead. Or use a [RegExp](http://de.selfhtml.org/javascript/objekte/regexp.htm) for the `','` like here:

```
var myExp = /,/g;
var vl = this.value.replace(myExp, '');
```

Try the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F2wEK/27/) it works fine for me.

Comment: This is what i wanted :) Thanks alexvii (you're rock)

Answer (score 1):

Change your replace function. It replaces only first occurrence of comma:

```
var vl = this.value.replace(/,/g, '');
```